# vertical align two divs next to each other to a same height?

Tags: html, css, tablecell

I want to align two divs (or something similar) next to each other to a same height.

Also the wrapper containing the two divs should be vertically aligned in center.

Tried something like this

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.innerWrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #32CD32;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div class="box">This is a box</div>
      <div class="box">
        <div>This is a box</div>
        <div>This is a box</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the height of the two divs to be same independent of the content inside each div.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with ***Flexbox***:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.innerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  padding: 25px 25px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #32CD32;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div class="box">This is a box</div>
      <div class="box">
        <div>This is a box</div>
        <div>This is a box</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, we can, but do we have any way (not using flexbox), where we can use `display: table-cell` for middle vertical alignment. Can something be done with the .box class divs to maintain them in same height ?

Answer (score 0):

just use  `display: flex;` in `.innerWrapper`

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.innerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
}

.box {

  padding: 25px 25px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #32CD32;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div class="box">This is a box</div>
      <div class="box">
        <div>This is a box</div>
        <div>This is a box</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or if you want box in middle.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.innerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #32CD32;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div class="box">This is a box</div>
      <div class="box">
        <div>This is a box</div>
        <div>This is a box</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `flex` to `.innerWrapper` and `margin-right` to `.box`

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.innerWrapper {
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
}

.box {
 margin-right: 15px;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #32CD32;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div class="box">This is a box</div>
      <div class="box">
        <div>This is a box</div>
        <div>This is a box</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that use `display: table;`. You can also put the maximum height or width, now it's just full, inside the container.

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
}

.innerWrapper {
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
  display:table-row;
}

.box {
  padding: 25px 25px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #32CD32;
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div class="box">This is a box</div>
      <div class="box">
        <div>This is a box</div>
        <div>This is a box</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyway, you can use flex, flexbox, grid ....

Comment: Yes that's correct to some extent but I also wanted the innerWrapper to be vertically aligned centered. This solution puts the innerWrapper to the top.

Answer (score 0):

**Without flexbox**

You need to adjust the use of table classes like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  border-spacing:10px;
}
/* Added this for centring*/
.wrapper:before,.wrapper:after {
  content:"";
  display: table-row;
}
/**/

.innerWrapper {
  display: table-row; /*modified*/
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  display: table-cell; /*modified*/
  padding: 25px 25px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #32CD32;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div class="box">This is a box</div>
      <div class="box">
        <div>This is a box</div>
        <div>This is a box</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can also achieve that using `display: table` but you have to change the other css a little bit. Here is the example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="innerWrapper">
      <div class="box">This is a box</div>
      <div class="box">
        <div>This is a box</div>
        <div>This is a box</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.innerWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.box {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background-color: #32CD32;
}
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/shihab_codepen/pen/wjQaEm)